# Handling of array; returned by methods in iOS UI Automation

Tags: javascript, ios, arrays, uia

I have been able to use all the methods for automating iphone app test except with ones which returns array... e.g  `elements()`

I have tried to do it using declaration of array as

```
var arr  =  [];
var arr  =  UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().mainWindow().tabBar().elements();
UIALogger.logPass("result"+ arr[0])     // just to get first element
```

But it is not working

Can someone ans how to handle `array`. What is the correcting required?

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you want from such array?

Here is an example how to handle array of elements:

```
function getAllNamesInList (list, index){

   var elem_list = list[index].elements();
   var elem_count = elem_list .length;
   var names = [];
   var elem_name;

   for (var elem_ind = 0;  elem_ind < elem_count ; elem_ind++){

      elem_name= elem_list [cell_ind].name();
      if (!elem_name){fail ("TEST_INFO: Empty Element name!!!");}
      names.push(elem_name);
   }

   return names;

};
```

Here is usage example of this function():

Your case:

```
var app =  UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp();
var window = app.mainWindow();
var arr  = window.tabBar()
var current_names = [];

current_names = getAllNamesInList (arr , 0);
UIALogger.logMessage ("Here are ALL names from array " + current_names );
```

Other possible lists which can be transferred and used within this function():

```
var table_views = window.tableViews();
var tab_bar = app.tabBar();
var nav_bar = app.navigationBar();
```